# Count the row if the first column has 1 and the rest columns are all zero

Tags: r, dplyr, countif

- I want to count the rows in which the first column is 1 and rest
  other columns are 0. Because I want to see how many subscribers just
  watched the first episode and not the rest of the episodes.
- Same way just the last episode.
- All the episodes
- Rows where first and last episodes are 0 but any of the episodes in between can be 0 or 1 (at least one in between has to be 1 and it can be multiple ones). In other words, someone who watched just the episodes in between but not the first or last.

I have tried to use the `dplyr` function in R using `mutate` and `ifelse` combined but it is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuFVM.jpg)

The first column is the subscriber id and the other columns are episode air date (in order). `1` represents that the subscriber watched that episode and `0` subscriber didn't watch the episode.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: Try `sum(df1[[2]]== 1 & !rowSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)] != 0) , na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the helper function `dplyr::if_all()` inside `dplyr::mutate()` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

# A simpler version of the dataset to illustrate
data <- tibble(
  "2021-07-07" = sample(c(1, 0), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  "2021-07-08" = sample(c(1, 0), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  "2021-07-09" = sample(c(1, 0), 1000, replace = TRUE),
)


data %>% 
  mutate(
    only_first = `2021-07-07` == 1 & if_all(-`2021-07-07`, ~ .x == 0)
  )
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 1,000 x 4
   `2021-07-07` `2021-07-08` `2021-07-09` only_first
          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <lgl>     
 1            0            1            1 FALSE     
 2            0            0            0 FALSE     
 3            0            1            0 FALSE     
 4            1            1            1 FALSE     
 5            1            0            1 FALSE     
 6            0            1            1 FALSE     
 7            1            1            0 FALSE     
 8            1            0            1 FALSE     
 9            1            1            0 FALSE     
10            1            0            0 TRUE      
# ... with 990 more rows
```

##### Breakdown of the logic

- `2021-07-07 == 1` matches rows where the first column equals 1
- `if_all(-2021-07-07, ~ .x == 0)` matches rows where **all** columns **except** the first equals 0.
- The `&` gives you `TRUE` if both statements described over are `TRUE`, and `FALSE` if not.

Comment: I used the code below for episodes in between and it worked.                                                 # episodes in between 
exp5<- pokergo_kmeans_wide_numeric %>% 
  mutate(
    in_between = `2021-07-07` == 0 & `2021-07-14` == 0 & if_any(-c(`2021-07-07`,`2021-07-14`), ~ .x == 1)
  )
But not for all episodes : exp4<- pokergo_kmeans_wide_numeric %>% 
  mutate( all_episodes = if_all( ~ .x == 0))

Comment: To check all columns you can use the select function `everything()`: `exp4<- pokergo_kmeans_wide_numeric %>% mutate( all_episodes = if_all(everything(), ~ .x == 0))`

Comment: This is amazing. It all worked. I learned something new today. Thank You!

Comment: You’re welcome! If my answer helped you, please consider “accepting” it by clicking the check mark next to the question.